# Phone takes blurry pictures

Tags: camera, 7.5

I have a Dell Venue Pro (DVP) with a 5 megapixel camera.  It is unable to capture pictures without very noticeable blur.  Besides building a tripod, what steps can I take to improve my picture-taking experience?

[image: All i did was point and shoot]

Comment: Are you looking for techniques you can use? If so, this might be better for photo.se

Comment: I was hoping for a phone setting, or some special software that works together with camera on the phone.  This is not a question about image editing.

Comment: I had Dell Venue Pros. My picture quality was drastically improved when I quit pushing the button to take a picture and started just tapping the screen. All the same, my 10 yr old daughter made her get her another phone besides the DVP as the picture quality was too sad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you probably know, blurry photos are caused when then camera is moved while the shutter is open.

Currently, there isn't any software on the phone that can eliminate blur, but there is a setting that might help reduce it. In your camera settings, set your ISO to either auto, or if you are adventurous set it to a high value.

The folks over at Photo.se can explain it, but in short the higher to number, the more light is let in, but the more noise is in the picture. The extra light should help the shutter speed.

That is about all I can give regarding settings in the phone. Unless the DVP is radically different, I haven't seen one that lets you control shutter speed or aperture.

I really recommend taking this to photo.se as well. They can help you on technique, and show you how to form your body into a stable tripod

Answer (score 4):

There are three places that I could find to make adjustments that relate to camera functionality on my DVP.

- Settings -> Applications tab -> Puctures + Camera
- Pictures -> ... (on the bottom) -> Settings
- Camera app -> Options icon

The third option seems to be the most relevant for my issue.

- Flash
- ISO gain
- White Balance
- Scene mode
- Metering mode
- Exposure compensation
- Anti Banding

Resetting to defaults fixed things for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Auto-Focus (in case you have not done earlier.)

**Tapping on Screen** or **Pressing the camera button half** before taking picture force the phone to auto-focus.

Hold camera still for some time after clicking the camera button so that there is no chance motion blur.

Comment: This is a common approach with most cameras.  I tried it, of course.  The attached picture is the best I can do.  And no, my hands are not shaking more than the usual.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you are in macro mode. Often, you can be in that mode without knowing, and then all normal pictures (not closeups) will be blurry.

Also check this blog post for hints and tips to get good pics: 
http://mywpstory.com/2012/04/camera-tip-taking-better-photos-with-your-new-nokia-lumia-900-windows-phone/

Comment: Good stuff, +1!